# Merge strings of hex numbers for serial communication in python

Tags: python, string, serial-port, hex

I am sending the messages to the COM port in the format `ser.write('\x01\x03\x01')` which works well.
I try to make a function that will work as following:

`def func(inp):

    # transport inp to hex format and to be like \xXY (two digits)

    # merge in the way '\x01'+'\xXY'+'\x01'`

But I always  have problems either with inserting the backslash (it can be inserted like double backslash but then the port can't read it as a single one) or with reading this backslash by interpretator (gives an error).
If someone has done it already, help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `binascii.unhexlify` to convert the hex string

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('010203') == '\x01\x02\x03'
True
```

So your function is

```
def func(inp):
    return '\x01' + binascii.unhexlify(inp) + '\x01';
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I don't know which one of offered solutions to use)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Python's [struct module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) is for. Your function can be written like:

```
import struct

>>> def func(inp):
...     return struct.pack('bbb', 1, inp, 1)
...
...
>>> func(22)
'\x01\x16\x01'
```

the `'b'` format character interprets byte values as signed chars, `'B'` will interpret them as unsigned chars.

Comment: Thank you! When I put 10 (to get 0A) the function interprets it as \n. Do you know by chance if the port will recognise the message in this way? (I don't have my board now)

Comment: Yes, that should be the correct behavior. It's only showing \01 like that because there's no other printable representation of that byte. The printable representation of 0x0A is a '\n' newline.